# How can I install the CxSAST server in local

Tags: eclipse-plugin, checkmarx

I have integrated [Checkmarks plugin in Eclipse](https://checkmarx.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/KC/pages/74317880/Setting+Up+the+CxSAST+Eclipse+Plugin). But while I am scanning the project, an authentication error is coming. Can you please help me out to solve this problem?

Comment: I am afraid currently there is too little information to provide an answer. At least the full error message would be necessary. Also more details about the environment, setup, used version, etc. and log files will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up a [CxSAST Server](https://checkmarx.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/KC/pages/569639218/Installing+CxSAST+v8.8.0+and+up) and point to it on the [Authentication form](https://checkmarx.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/KC/pages/126446016/Setting+Up+the+CxSAST+Eclipse+Plugin+v8.4.2+and+up).

Comment: Can this be done locally on a pc without acquiring some kind of paid license? (The instructions in the link refer to, and recommend, some license.)